# How can i disable multiple inputs with JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried this

```
  <body>
    <input placeholder="test1" class="input"/>
    <input placeholder="test2" class="input"/>
  </body>
  <script>
       document.querySelector(".input").disabled = true;
  </script>
```

[image]

Why is the second input (test2) not disabled.
Thanks!

Comment: The `.querySelector()` function will only ever return 1 element (or `null`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.querySelector` only selects the first instance of what your searching for, you need to use `document.querySelectorAll('input')` to select all the instances of your inputs, which returns an array you can go through,

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input')
for (let i = 0;i<inputs.length;i++) {
  inputs[i].disabled = true
}
```

Alternatively use ForEach

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input')
inputs.forEach((input)=>{
  input.disabled = true
})
```

Comment: FWIW, `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList`, and `forEach()` doesn't support NodeLists in Internet Explorer.

Comment: You can use `Array.from` to convert to an array before using for each. `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.input')).forEach()`

Answer (score 2):

Try [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Run the snippet below:

```js
var allinputs = document.querySelectorAll('.input');
for (var i = 0, len = allinputs.length; i<len; i++){
    allinputs[i].disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<input class="input"></input>
<input class="input"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wrap the inputs in a `<fieldset> ... </fieldset>` tag and set the disabled attribute on that `<fieldset disabled>` - all children inputs will be disabled .

```css
input:disabled {
 cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

```html
  <fieldset disabled>
    <legend>Fieldset disabled - causes all children inputs to be disabled:</legend>
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
    <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
    <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
  
  <hr/>
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Fieldset not disabled:</legend>
    <label for="fname">First name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br><br>
    <label for="lname">Last name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br><br>
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>
    <label for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
    <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday"><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </fieldset>
```